# Getting crooked design while running pyqt apps on osx

Tags: python-2.7, qt, pyqt

I am using Qt designer and python to develop and run GUI on osx.
During the design stages, the designer displays menus and buttons according to the osx app styles, as it should, but when i run my script using an IDE or a python terminal i am getting a different design.

Qt designer display:
[image]

Python launcher/ide/terminal display:
[image]

I have tried changing the app style from within my script:

```
def main():
    app = QtGui.QApplication(argv)  
    app.setStyle('mac') # change to mac app style
    form = MainWindow()             
    form.show()                        
    app.exec_()                        
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

it will change but the style is still different than what it should be.

Has anybody else experienced issues of this sort?

Answer (score 0):

Try [setting the style](https://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qapplication.html#setStyle-2) *before* creating the application object:

```
QtGui.QApplication.setStyle('macintosh')
app = QtGui.QApplication(argv)
```

If that doesn't work, check that the necessary style plugin is available:

```
for key in QtGui.QStyleFactory.keys():
    print(str(key))
```

If "macintosh" (or something like that) isn't shown, there may be something wrong with your PyQt or Qt installation (not exactly sure what, though).

Comment: Thanks ekhumoro, i have the 'Macintosh (aqua)' style, it just wouldn't behave the way it should...

Comment: @AmitEven. So have you solved the problem? Did you try the code in my question?

Comment: .What i meant was that i can change the app style, and i have the macintosh style available but it looks different than the way it should be as displayed in Qt designer.